# Sending FCM Push Notification to topic but preventing duplicate notification

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating an app in which users can subscribe to multiple topics.
Whenever a news article is shared within the app, it is assigned multiple topics.
Users receive push notifications whenever a news article that is relevant to a topic they subscribed to is shared.

Say a user subscribed to topics A and B.
A news article that belongs to both of these topics (A & B) gets shared.
In this case, what happens in my code is,

```
for(const topic of topics) {
  ...
  admin.messaging().send(message);
  ...
}
```

So the user will receive two push notifications, one for topic A and one for topic B.
Since I'm sending FCM push notifications not to specific devices but to topics, I cannot keep track of who received the push notifications, so I cannot prevent duplicate notifications manually.

Would there be a way for me to make sure the user does not receive the same fcm push notification twice (i.e. receive the push notification only for topicA and not for topic B)?

I am handling both the server-side (TypeScript) and client-side (Flutter), so a solution for either side will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is a single call to `send` to send to all topics [using a  condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics).

Given your example of topic A and topic B, that'd be:

```
const condition = '\'stock-GOOG\' in topics || \'industry-tech\' in topics';

const message = ;

admin.messaging().send({
  notification: {
    title: 'Your notification title',
    body: 'Your notification body'
  },
  condition: "'TopicA' in topics ||'TopicB' in topics"
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank! I was able to sort this out using conditions as you suggested.

Comment: Just a comment for anyone else who run into this problem: If the || operator in the condition does not work, try this : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/183#issuecomment-648758538